# Calculate working days without holidays fast in PHP

Tags: php

I need to calculate the working days between a huge set of dates. Therefore I am searching for a function that does it quickly

Set all holidays:

```
public function getArrayOfHolidays($year, $holidays= array(), $format = 'Y-m-d')
    {
        $special1= new DateTime('2017-10-31');
        array_push($holidays, $special1->format($format));

        $newyear= new DateTime();
        $newyear->modify('1 january ' . $year);
        array_push($holidays, $newyear->format($format));

        $holyThreeKings= new DateTime();
        $holyThreeKings->modify('6 january ' . $year);
        array_push($holidays, $holyThreeKings->format($format));

        $layborDay= new DateTime();
        $layborDay->modify('1 may ' . $year);
        array_push($holidays, $layborDay->format($format));

        $unityDay= new DateTime();
        $unityDay->modify('3 october ' . $year);
        array_push($holidays, $unityDay->format($format));

        $allSaintsDay= new DateTime();
        $allSaintsDay->modify('1 november ' . $year);
        array_push($holidays, $allSaintsDay->format($format));

        $christmasEve= new DateTime();
        $christmasEve->modify('24 december ' . $year);
        array_push($holidays, $christmasEve->format($format));

        $christmas1 = new DateTime();
        $christmas1->modify('25 december ' . $year);
        array_push($holidays, $christmas1->format($format));

        $christmas2 = new DateTime();
        $christmas2->modify('26 december ' . $year);
        array_push($holidays, $christmas2->format($format));

        $silvester = new DateTime();
        $silvester->modify('31 december ' . $year);
        array_push($holidays, $silvester->format($format));

        $easterSunday= new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', easter_date($year)));
        $easterSunday->modify('+1 day');
        array_push($holidays, $easterSunday->format($format));

        $goodFriday = new DateTime($ostersonntag->format('Y-m-d'));
        $goodFriday->modify('last friday');
        array_push($holidays, $goodFriday->format($format));

        $easterMonday= new DateTime($ostersonntag->format('Y-m-d'));
        $easterMonday->modify('next monday');
        array_push($holidays, $easterMonday->format($format));

        $ascensionOfJesus= new DateTime($ostersonntag->format('Y-m-d'));
        $ascensionOfJesus->modify('+39 days');
        array_push($holidays, $ascensionOfJesus->format($format));

        $pentecostSunday= new DateTime($ostersonntag->format('Y-m-d'));
        $pentecostSunday->modify('+49 days');
        array_push($holidays, $pentecostSunday->format($format));

        $pentecostMonday= new DateTime($ostersonntag->format('Y-m-d'));
        $pentecostMonday->modify('+50 days');
        array_push($holidays, $pentecostMonday->format($format));

        $corpusChristi = new DateTime($pentecostMonday->format('Y-m-d'));
        $corpusChristi ->modify('next sunday');
        $corpusChristi ->modify('next thursday');
        array_push($holidays, $corpusChristi ->format($format));

        return $holidays;
    }
```

This runs a maximum of 3 times to make sure I have all holydays for the previous and the next year if there are dates calculated in between years. Therefore should not have that high of an impact. I still wanted to show it because there sure are better ways to do it? Of course I could pre-calculate the next X years and store them in a database, maybe that would be better.

now this is the function I use for calculating the workdays:

```
public function getWorkingDays($startDate, $endDate, $holidays)
    {
        // do strtotime calculations just once
        $endDate = strtotime($endDate);
        $startDate = strtotime($startDate);


        //The total number of days between the two dates. We compute the no. of seconds and divide it to 60*60*24
        //We add one to include both dates in the interval.
        $days = ($endDate - $startDate) / 86400 + 1;

        $no_full_weeks = floor($days / 7);
        $no_remaining_days = fmod($days, 7);

        //It will return 1 if it's Monday,.. ,7 for Sunday
        $the_first_day_of_week = date("N", $startDate);
        $the_last_day_of_week = date("N", $endDate);

        //---->The two can be equal in leap years when February has 29 days, the equal sign is added here
        //In the first case the whole interval is within a week, in the second case the interval falls in two weeks.
        if ($the_first_day_of_week <= $the_last_day_of_week) {
            if ($the_first_day_of_week <= 6 && 6 <= $the_last_day_of_week) $no_remaining_days--;
            if ($the_first_day_of_week <= 7 && 7 <= $the_last_day_of_week) $no_remaining_days--;
        } else {
            // (edit by Tokes to fix an edge case where the start day was a Sunday
            // and the end day was NOT a Saturday)

            // the day of the week for start is later than the day of the week for end
            if ($the_first_day_of_week == 7) {
                // if the start date is a Sunday, then we definitely subtract 1 day
                $no_remaining_days--;

                if ($the_last_day_of_week == 6) {
                    // if the end date is a Saturday, then we subtract another day
                    $no_remaining_days--;
                }
            } else {
                // the start date was a Saturday (or earlier), and the end date was (Mon..Fri)
                // so we skip an entire weekend and subtract 2 days
                $no_remaining_days -= 2;
            }
        }

        //The no. of business days is: (number of weeks between the two dates) * (5 working days) + the remainder
        //---->February in none leap years gave a remainder of 0 but still calculated weekends between first and last day, this is one way to fix it
        $workingDays = $no_full_weeks * 5;
        if ($no_remaining_days > 0) {
            $workingDays += $no_remaining_days;
        }

        //We subtract the holidays
        foreach ($holidays as $holiday) {
            $time_stamp = strtotime($holiday);
            //If the holiday doesn't fall in weekend
            if ($startDate <= $time_stamp && $time_stamp <= $endDate && date("N", $time_stamp) != 6 && date("N", $time_stamp) != 7)
                $workingDays--;
        }

        return $workingDays;
    }
```

now that function is called about 40.000 times in a loop which takes about 20secs. Is there a more efficient way to do that? Or is the only option to cache it?

Comment: So is there actually a _problem_ with this code? Or is it working as expected? If your code works but you're looking to improve it, SO isn't the place to ask. [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is there for such questions.

Comment: Well the code is gernerally working, i didn't know that there is an extra place for reviews. I'm sorry for posting in the wrong forum =(

Comment: It's fine m8. I wasn't the one that downvoted your question here btw. I simply pointed you in the right direction :) Hope you'll find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use the florianv/business composer library to do this:

https://github.com/florianv/business

Documentation is good and it runs faster than anything I have come up with on my own.

Once you define your parameters (opening hours for each day, holidays), you use the "timeline" function to determine how many days are between two dates for a business.

Comment: Tank you i will check that out.